# jQuery .on() input field inside Kendo Grid not binding correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

So lately I've been working on a screen that has this Grid in it (Kendo).... One of the templates that the Grid uses displays a simple button like this:

```
<input type="button" class="iqs-review-btn btn btn-primary" value="REVIEW" />
```

And I'm trying to bind a click action on it so I can do some stuff that I need to... but I can't seem to bind it correctly. This is the JS code I'm using to add the event:

```
 $('resultsGrid').on('click', 'input.iqs-review-btn', function (e) {

    }
});
```

I already binded other elements inside the grid with different events and they all seem to work fine but for whatever reason this button does nothing when clicked... Thanks a lot for any help you can provide and have a great day! :)

Comment: Have you tried with `$(document).on("click", 'input.iqs-review-btn', function (e) {`

Comment: What's **resultsGrid** a class an id?!

Comment: Is your selector missing a dot or a hash? $('.resultsGrid') or $('#resultsGrid')

Comment: Ok so I think I must be overworking and probably not on top of my game... Seriously after like 1 hour of trying this I decide to post it here to finally find out I was missing the # on the selector.... And I have all other event bindings like 5 lines of code away all with the correct selector and somehow I missed it.... But yeah that was it... Thank you all for reminding my that I need to sleep sometimes or stuff like this will happen :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your jquery element selector is missing a dot or a hash?

```
 $('.resultsGrid')
```

or

```
$('#resultsGrid')
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that Kendo Grid is refreshed and you lose the event.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.iqs-review-btn', function () {
});
```